# Starting a Screen Sessions Upon Reboot and Executing a Script in It

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, gnu-screen

I would like to have a certain script run in a screen session when an Ubuntu 22.04 system starts up. The command I came up with is as follows

```
screen fauxpilot -dmS sh ./fauxpilot/launch.sh
```

However, it does not appear to be creating any screen sessions. What am doing wrong?

Also, how can I include a graceful shutdown of this process upon the system's shutdown? At the moment, I am planning to run the startup command from cron as follows

```
@reboot screen fauxpilot -dmS sh ./fauxpilot/launch.sh
```